# How to save the original image by replacing proxy?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am doing an  photo editor apllication..
i came to know that we can create jpeg using canvas(any UIElement)
i am taking a proxy(smaller size) image while in editing mode.
i am not getting how to save the original image by replacing proxy without rendering the original image on screen.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Before saving change the canvas size to original width height
- say canvas.updatelayout()
- convert UIElement to writeable bitmap
- Scale down the image to previous width and height